# Swift string construction was too complex to be solved in reasonable time

Tags: swift, xcode

Here is my code:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/submit.php")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postString = "user_name="+user_name+"&first_name="+first_name.text+"&last_name="+last_name.text+"&company_name="+company_name.text+"&location="+location.text+"&phone="+phone.text+"&website="+website.text+"&email="+email.text+"&about="+about.text
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
}
task.resume()
```

when I try to run the app, it gives me the following error on `postString`:

> Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Comment: Do what the compiler is telling you. Instead of stuffing everything in the same expression, make several ones, it will help the compiler know what happens. :)

Comment: @EricD thanks for that. how would i do it?

Comment: You have one big declaration of `postString`, with many variables that you add to Strings, on a single line. Instead, first make a part of it, like the names, and store this in a variable; then add the rest, using another line. Like `let names = xxx + xxx` then do `let postString = names + xxx + xxx`, etc.

Comment: Is the quote at the end of the PHP URL missing in your actual code too? (Also, avoid direct string concatenation, use string interpolation instead: `"user_name=\(user_name)&first_name=\(first_name.text)&..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let parameters = ["user_name" : user_name,
    "first_name" : first_name.text,
    "last_name" : last_name.text,
    "company_name" : company_name.text,
    "location" : location.text,
    "phone" : phone.text,
    "website" : website.text,
    "email" : email.text,
    "about" : about.text].map { "\($0)=\($1 ?? "")" }
let postString = parameters.joinWithSeparator("&")
```

The solution will first create a dictionary with the parameters and their values (this will also improve readability and maintainability of your code).

Then it will execute a "map" on that dictionary, turning it into an array of strings containing `key=value` (and if since `text` on `UITextField` is optional it will set it to an empty string if it's nil).

Lastly it will create a string by joining all strings in the array with the separator `&`

Comment: What does this mean? `.map { "\($0)=\($1 ?? "")" }`

Comment: The `map` will transform the dictionary into an array of strings $0 = the key and $1 = the value in the dictionary. For more information about the map-function; http://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/. In short; for every element in whatever we're mapping - execute this function, and store the returning value of that function into a new array